# I have an issue Where my code's variables that have been inputed in my tkinter module come out as .!entry and not what the person inputer

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue Where my code's variables that have been inputed in my tkinter module come out as .!entry and not what the person inputed. In the image i show it always says .!entry however when i send it to file it says .!entry,.!entry2[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f79wS.png). any ideas how to fix this?

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

def newUser():
    global win
    win=Tk()
    win.title("Prototype Register") #name of popup
    win.geometry("500x300")#size


    win.option_add( "*font", "segoeui 15 bold italic" )
    win.resizable(False, False)

    global Username
    global Password #maskes them available in all functions

    Label(win,text="Please create a user name and password").place(x=20,y=10) # a message fo user
    win.option_add( "*font", "segoeui 20 bold italic" )#font
    Label(win,text="Username").place(x=30,y=50)
    Label(win,text="Password").place(x=30,y=110)     #creates texts

    Username=Entry(win) #code for theinput box
    Username.place(x=180,y=50) # creates input box

    Password=Entry(win) #created an input area
    Password.place(x=180,y=110) #location

    print(Username)
    Button(win,text="Create User",command=addData,height=2,width=10,bd=4).place(x=180,y=170)#button
    
 ###########################################           
def addData():
    win.destroy()

    global Username

    global Password

    print(Username)
    Logins=open("Userdata.txt","a")

    print(Username,Password,file=Logins,sep=",")

    Logins.close()
newUser()
```

Comment: do u mind stating where I would use this in my code or how it is used

Comment: Did you mean: `print(Username.get())`?

Comment: Use `Username.get()` wherever you want to get the input value of `Username` widget. For example, `print(Username.get())` and `print(Username.get(), Password.get(), file=Logins, ...)`.

Comment: so now i have an errors such as         _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"

Comment: It is because you have destroyed the main window.

Comment: Move `win.destroy()` to end of `addData()`.